# How to set fixed Names to UITextField for Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have around 10 Admin Names for whom only the admin panel is visible.I want to hardcode these names, so that when any admin enters his name among the 10 admin names he should be able to use the admin panel i.e. Next View Controller.
I tried this but its working for only one name.
`

```
       if (![_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin1234"])
    {
    popMessage=@"Please Enter Valid User Id";
    retvalue=NO;
    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take NSArray of names and need to check values from array.

```
    BOOL check = YES;
    NSString *popMessage;
    NSArray *arr =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",@"def",@"xyx",@"xxx", nil];


    if (![arr containsObject:_txtUserId.text])
    {
        popMessage=@"Please Enter Valid User Id";
        check=NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work in 2 ways

**Way 1**

```
if ([_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin1234"] ||
    [_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin2nd"]) ||
    [_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin2nd"])
{
 //take user to screen

}else{
 popMessage=@"Please Enter Valid User Id";
 retvalue=NO;
 }
```

**2nd Way**

Add all of your names in array, and then compare text with user input

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin1234"] || [_txtUserId.text isEqualToString:@"Admin12345"] || and so on)
    {
  push to next VC
    }`
else
{
error
}
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working... Infact both strings wont work @Rahul Patel